# When python code is executed, gui is empty

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

whenever i execute this code, nothing shows up on the gui. it works fine if i use grid for placing labels and buttons. it doesnt show anything if i use .place to place the labels.

```
from Tkinter import *


class Applet(Frame):
""" First attempt to make the program """
    def __init__(self, master):
            """ initialize the frame """
            Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.login()
    #self.Signup()
    def login(self):
            self.Login_username = StringVar()
            self.Login_password = StringVar()
            self.Label1 = Label(self, text = 'Username: ').place(x = 0, y = 0)
            self.Label2 = Label(self, text = 'Password: ').place(x =50, y = 0)
            self.loguser = Entry(self, textvariable = self.Login_username, width = 15).place(x = 0, y = 10)
            self.logpass = Entry(self, textvariable = self.Login_password, width = 15, show = '*').place(x = 50, y = 10)
            self.button = Button(self, text = 'Login').place(x = 400, y = 0)



Top = Tk()
Top.title('test-gui')
app = Applet(Top)
Top.geometry('700x350')
Top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't know TKinter but what is the return value of .place()?  If it returns the instance great, otherwise that might become an additional problem down the road.

Comment: @David: Like most mutating methods in idiomatic Python, it returns `None`, so yes, it is an additional problem down the road. As was already explained in the answer.

Comment: @abarnert I wrote that comment before you posted your question but got a phone call, when I got back I posted... hence missing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're just creating a bunch of objects and adding them to an interface that isn't itself added anywhere.

The simplest way to add them to the interface is to just call the `pack` method on the `Applet`.

However, you're still going to have some problems.

First, you're trying to explicitly `place` all your elements almost on top of each other, so they're all going to overlap in a big mess.

Second, the `place` method returns `None`, so all of your member variables are going to be `None`, not the actual widgets.

Here's a version that solves all three problems:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Applet(Frame):
    """ First attempt to make the program """
    def __init__(self, master):
            """ initialize the frame """
            Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.login()
    #self.Signup()
    def login(self):
            self.Login_username = StringVar()
            self.Login_password = StringVar()
            self.Label1 = Label(self, text = 'Username: ')
            self.Label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
            self.Label2 = Label(self, text = 'Password: ')
            self.Label2.place(x = 100, y = 0)
            self.loguser = Entry(self, textvariable = self.Login_username, width = 15)
            self.loguser.place(x = 0, y = 20)
            self.logpass = Entry(self, textvariable = self.Login_password, width = 15, show = '*')
            self.logpass.place(x = 100, y = 20)
            self.button = Button(self, text = 'Login')
            self.button.place(x = 400, y = 20)

Top = Tk()
Top.title('test-gui')
app = Applet(Top)
app.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
Top.geometry('700x350')
Top.mainloop()
```

However, you're usually better off using boxes and the `pack` method instead of explicitly calling `place`. For example, the `x = 100` instead of `x = 50`, etc., works on my system, making everything lay out nicely—but if your system has different default font sizes, widget boundaries, etc., it will end up overlapping or weirdly spaced.